# How to store an array as a value of a key in another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, key-value-store

I am trying to store an array as a value of a key in another array.
I can't use functions like array_push() or a for loop because the second array is being created as a parameter of a function.

I've googled for hours and can't find any answers! I'm new to PHP so I have no idea if this is even possible.

The first array is something like:

```php
    $choices[] = array('1'=>'Blue','2'=>'Red)
```

EDIT: *this is the code I meant to add*

```php
    $choices[] = array('1'=>'Blue','2'=>'Red');
```

*The lack of `'` and `;` were a typo. The array is being created in a much more complex way. In my attempt to abstract and simplify it to post it here I missed the `'` and `;` . Kudos to @diéfani-favareto-piovezan for spotting that.*

Now I want to insert this array as a value of a key in another array that is being created in another part of the code:

```php
     return randomFunction('random text', array(
                                   'a' => 'apple',
                                   'b' => 'banana',
                                   'c' =>  ,
                                  )

                          )
```

I want array `$choices` to be the value of key `'c'`.

I tried this

```php
     return randomFunction('random text', array(
                                   'a' => 'apple',
                                   'b' => 'banana',
                                   'c' => $choices,
                                  ),

                          )
```

but it gives me an error

EDIT: *I meant to say that I tried this*

```php
     return randomFunction('random text', array(
                                   'a' => 'apple',
                                   'b' => 'banana',
                                   'c' => $choices,
                                  )

                          )
```

*Once again, when trying to abstract and simplify (the actual array created in the RandomFunction has about 250 lines) I added the extra comma by mistake. Kudos to @brevis, @Nick and @tim for spotting this and bringing it to my attention.*

```php
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' in /filename.php line 120
```

The error mentions another line down the code, but I know that it is not the cause because if I remove

```php
                                   'c' => $choices,
```

there is no error.

EDIT: *I meant to say "before I added the `'c'` line" (and not "if I remove it" ), there were no errors. I also could have added that the creation of `$choices` comes before the `randomFunction` array, so that's another reason why I knew there were no errors there.*

*CONCLUSION: 
As I mentioned, the error was an extra `),` after the `'c'` line, which I failed to reproduce here when trying to simplify the code. I think that when I added the `'c'` line in my actual code I must have added an extra `),` by mistake. I was only able to find that because @nick said that the `randomFunction` code (the one after "I tried this") should be working. That was the answer I needed to confirm that the error was not on that line. Thanks to to @dont-panic's comment, I looked more carefully into the error message I was getting and found the extra `)'`. At the end of the day, eveybody helped me. So thank you all!*

*To anyone who has come across this, the working code is*:

```php
    $choices[] = array('1'=>'Blue','2'=>'Red');

     return randomFunction('random text', array(
                                   'a' => 'apple',
                                   'b' => 'banana',
                                   'c' => $choices,
                                  )

                          );
```

*

Comment: In this case 99% error on coma after closing bracket of array(

Comment: The code you have written (other than the spurious comma after the array) is fine. You need to show us all the code, *including* the line with the actual error message, if you want help

Comment: Why is that line relevant? I already said that there is no error if I remove the 'c' line.

Comment: That line may not be the direct cause of the error, but the problem we have here is that the error is not reproducible from the code in your question. There are syntax errors in the code you've shown, just not syntax errors that would cause the specific parse error you're getting.

Comment: cant debug an "example", hey doctor here is an example of a broken arm, not mine, but can you fix the example for me.

Comment: Have you heard of something called abstraction? or simplification? The code I'm working with is much more complex and I didn't want to get people confused. So I simplified it.  In fact, Stack overflow asked me to do this when I was entering the question. Like I said, I am new to PHP (started learning it this week), so I missed a end quote in the simplification. And again, like I said, there were no errors if I removed the 'c' line, so you should have assumed that there was no error in the $choices line.

Comment: But you guys were right in saying that I should have entered the whole code. You would have probably spotted the extra ), right away. The problem is that the second array is very long (about 250 lines), so I wanted to keep it short. I guess it ended up being too short.

Comment: nick spotted the extra comma an hour ago, 2nd comment

Comment: No the problem was in a part of the code that I didn't show. When I tried to simplify it to write it here, I ended up not showing it (and made some typos in the process). I guess next time I will post the 250+ lines of code :D or hopefully there won't be a next time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the error:

I was adding an extra `),` at the end of the second array.

The working code is

```
$choices[] = array('1'=>'Blue','2'=>'Red');

 return randomFunction('random text', array(
                               'a' => 'apple',
                               'b' => 'banana',
                               'c' => $choices,
                              )

                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a single quote mark and semicolon after Red.

Try this and see if it works:

```
$choices[] = array('1'=>'Blue','2'=>'Red');
```

Comment: The code is just an example. The array is being created in a much more complex way. And like I said, there is no error if I remove the 'c' line.